# click a button within a scroll view in stead of clicking the screen in " Auotscroll" sample code,

Tags: ios, button, scrollview

In Apple sample code: " Autoscroll " - the second sample code of " ScrollViewSuite " sample code, when tap the screen, a thumb view pop-up ( slide -up ) from the bottom by the following code:

## pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

```
- (void)tapDetectingImageView:(TapDetectingImageView *)view gotSingleTapAtPoint:(CGPoint)tapPoint {
    // Single tap shows or hides drawer of thumbnails.
    [self toggleThumbView];
}
```

`enter code here`

and now, I add a vertical scroll view ( with buttons in it) to the UIView, when click one of the buttons within the scroll view, a thumb view pop-up ( slide -up ) from the bottom.

How to achieve this?

thanks!

Comment: solved, when I restart my Xcode, the event appears. thx